# Selenium WebDriver - Application becomes unresponsive after clicking on Save button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am automating one of the scenario which contains entering few details and then click on Save button. Manually when i am performing the steps, it hardly takes 5 to 8 sec to process and complete.
But same performing via automation script, it just keep on loading for infinite time.

Below is the html code for Save button :

```
<button class="blueFilledButton ng-binding" ng-click="validateIdea(validateIdeaForm)" ng-disabled="userNotFound || PoupupButtonDisabled || incorrectValidDate" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Save</button>
```

Selenium code: I have tried with below click methods :

Case - 1 :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Save']")).click();
```

Case - 2 :

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Save']"))).click().perform();
```

In both the cases it just keeps on loading.

Is it due to any script is being invoked after clicking on Save button, and webdriver is not compatible with it?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add page html for reference

Comment: Is there any error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared the `<button>` with text as **Save** is a *Angular Element* so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='blueFilledButton ng-binding'][@ng-click=\"validateIdea(validateIdeaForm)\"]"))).click();
```